# Don't share the source code on the end user

Tags: security

I don't wanna share my source code on the end user. Like jsp/html code.  Any person in the client side will not be  able to copy my source code.

Comment: That is a problem every craftsman has: product copy. Load the HTML per AJAX, asynchrone loading of HTML DOM per JavaScript. Until you really need to put much effort in such side-issues, accept the situation. One advice: in JSP use `<%-- --%>` comments, not HTML comments.

Comment: Obfuscate it and minify it if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

As of web applications, HTML code is pretty much useless without the server side. Everyone can copy Google Docs' HTML code, but noone does because it's useless without having the server-based application logic.